# Discard first 10 bits of a number

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I am using serial protocol to transfer stream of analog input values (range 0-1023) directly into computer. This is how I typically encode a value:

```
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
// Numbers 0-255
buffer[++buffer_pos] = (sensorValue >> 0) & 0xff;
// Multiplies of 256, 0 - 3
buffer[++buffer_pos] = (sensorValue >> 8) & 0xff;
```

Note that this is little endian, I send least significant numbers first.

On java side in the computer, I use little bit more clumsy algorithm, since java doesn't support unsigned bytes:

```
short number = 0;
for(byte i=0; i<2; i++) {
  short received = (short)myPort.read();
  // turn unsigned to signed
  if(received<0)
    received = (short)((short)255+received);
  // first byte are just plain numbers 0-255
  if(i==0)
    number += received;
  // Second byte are multiplies of 256
  else
    number += received*256;
}
```

This means I just use 10 of 16 bits in my stream. I could compress the data more, but instead I want to use remaining 6 bits to send data. My scenario then is:

[image: image description]

I want to discard the first ten bits to get the flags:

[image: image description]

I tried this:

```
  // Remove first ten bits from number
  println("Code: "+(number>>10));
```

Didn't work - it would print same value for different large numbers:

```
Too large number received: 24108
Code: 23
Too large received: 24109
Code: 23
```

Comment: Exactly which bits, from which bytes, do you want to keep?

Comment: its peculiar that you are drawing the bits left to right

Comment: @gpasch I tried to draw them in the order they came. I will edit to make it clear I am using little endian, means that the least significant bytes are sent first.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working code extraction, based on the assumption that you send the bits in strict LSB as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 Bits are sent off in this order (LSB)

1. `01234567`
2. `89ABCDEF`

on the Java side you read them, first do some math to shift it up and add the second byte. Since Java is big endian, you have now effectively reverted the bits if interpreted as a number in Java:

```
89ABCDEF 01234567
```

To get a usable number in Java not a bitfield, you need to reverse it:

```
FEDCBA98 76543210
```

I double checked this in the docs:

> If an operand is more than one byte in size, then it is stored in
>   big-endian order - high-order byte first. For example, an unsigned
>   16-bit index into the local variables is stored as two unsigned bytes,
>   byte1 and byte2, such that its value is (byte1 << 8) | byte2. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html)

Since you are interpreting the code from the bits, you need it as Java values.

Input is in Arduino order bits: 12345..F:

```
arduino: 47461 == 1010 0110 1001 1101 Bits 0123 4567 89AB CDEF
javaInt: 42653 == 1010 0110 1001 1101 Bits interpreted by Java
numeric: 47461 == 1011 1001 0110 0101 Bits reorderd to Java order F..0
```

I took your method and rewrote it to use ints to get rid of the sign bit extension.

```
int number = 0;
// simulating arduino using bytearray stream.
ByteArrayInputStream myPort = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {(byte) 0b11011010, (byte) 0b10100101});
int received = myPort.read();
number = number | (received<<8);
received = myPort.read();
number = number | received;

System.out.println("arduino:  " + number + " == " + Integer.toBinaryString(number));

// reverse the bits to get Java understandable bit order for numeric values
int numericJavaInt = 0;
for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
    int bit = (number & 1<<(15-i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    numericJavaInt = numericJavaInt | bit<<i;
}

System.out.println("Java-Num: " + numericJavaInt + " == " + Integer.toBinaryString(numericJavaInt));

final int code = numericJavaInt >> 10;
System.out.println("6 upper bits code: " + code + " == " + Integer.toBinaryString(code));
```

Comment: but he wants to DISCARD the 10 bits - did you hear that?

Comment: This works perfectly for getting the low 10 bits for value, but I was asking how to get the high bits which contain the flags. I tried to simply invert the mask you've given but that didn't work well. I need to get 0-64 values, instead it gave me weird results, such as same result for 2048 and 2049 when doing `2049&0b1111110000000000`.

Comment: 2048 and 2049 differ by the lowest bit only which you did delete out by reverting the mask.

Comment: I'm pretty sure endianness only applies to the order of bytes within the whole variable, not to bits within each byte. `89ABCDEF 01234567` is the correct reconstruction of the original number.

Comment: I had to test, Java uses the bits from high to low, see my answer.

Comment: @thst Thank you very much for your help. I am sure going to return to this answer in the future, it's quite helpful in many ways! :)

Answer (score 1):

For labeling the bits, not talking about their values, the bits you receive from the stream are, in order left-first:

```
0123456789ABCDEF
```

You are placing them into a short in this order:

```
89ABCDEF01234567
```

Shifting 10 bits right as you tried then leaves you with this:

```
89ABCD
```

If I understand correctly, what you actually want is:

```
ABCDEF
```

To get that, you should shift only 8 bits right, and mask the left 2 with a bitwise and:

```
(number >> 8) & 0xC0
```

Also, for correcting the sign of a negative byte, you should add 256, not 255.